# private static and private methods dilemma

Tags: c#

Hi (again with philosophical question),

there is a `private static` method that does not have an access to instance fields and as far as my readings are concerned those methods provide a little bit of performance improvement.

> After you mark the methods as static, the compiler will emit
>   non-virtual call sites to these members. Emitting non-virtual call
>   sites will prevent a check at runtime for each call that ensures that
>   the current object pointer is non-null. This can result in a
>   measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code. In some
>   cases, the failure to access the current object instance represents a
>   correctness issue.

***FxCop***

Then why to use normal `private` method when we can place an instance field in `private static` method parameters? Isn't that inefficient?

Just to visualize what I mean:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly string _key = "ssss";

    public bool IsGoodKey()
    {
    }

    private static bool ValidateKeyStatic(string key)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(key);
    }
    private bool ValidateKey()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key);
    }
}
```

And now there are two ways of implementing `IsGoodKey`:

```
    public bool IsGoodKey()
    {
        return ValidateKeyStatic(_key);
    }
```

And

```
    public bool IsGoodKey()
    {
        return ValidateKey();
    }
```

Why don't **always** use `private static`?

Comment: Any operation that you do to mutate your state has to be public and will not take the same type as argument. Normally we use the helper methods in the class as private static or public static so that in order to get a new object or to get some operation, i don't need to new up the entire object not knowing its dependencies. Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: @Saravanan: "Any operation that you do to mutate your state has to be public" that's not true at all. Likewise "and will not take the same type as argument" - um, it might. For example, you could have a method to copy properties from one object into another.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you are right, I was trying to mention that it should be non-static but mentioned as public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If performance would be the entire purpose of `static`, then of course you could make *anything* `static`. But actually the keyword isn´t about **performance**, it´s about **semantics** - that is does the member belong to the **class** (and thus all instances), or to a **specific** instance of your class?

Imagine you´d create multiple instances of your class. If every instance had a `_key`, you surely need an **instance**-field, not a `static` one. If on the other hand all instances share the same key, you could make it `static` of course.

After all performance is just a side-effect of the keyword and you should **never** make design-decisions on pure performance-considerations.

Comment: Why is the call not virtual? `ValidateKey()` is a virtual call, the fact that the method is delcared as virtual or not doesn't make a difference. The emitted IL still is a `callvirt` and the compiler will always have to perform a non null check on `this` when the method is invoked.

Comment: What you are saying is completely right but I feel like my question still haven't been answered here. Behavior of static method is encapsulated withing the class. Lets say that `_key` has a different value in other instances. Why don't use 'static' methods with suitable parameter to conclude something withing that method. OOP will be still not validated and code will be more efficient just by adding `static` (that is only one word). I can understand one concern here. `private static` should not change class state. But in other cases I can't see any drawbacks

Comment: @Pawel Well, having every method static you completely lose any benefit of OOP, which is polymorphism. How would you override any method from a base-class? How would you ever implement any interface?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeap, I'm not talking about public methods. Only private here :)

Comment: @Pawel Okay, I see your point. So instead of using `myInstance.DoSomething()`, you use `DoSomething(myInstance)`, right? Well, I guess the performance-advantage is is neglectable for most scenarious, whereas the actual semantics I mentioned above are more important.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I just want to use in `IsGood()` method  `Validate(_key)` instead of `Validate()` that will will have an access to instance fields.

Comment: I just benchmarked it. It around 2 ns difference in this example.

Comment: @Pawel Wow, 2ns... is this **significant** to you? And by benchmark, you ment do the same operation some millions of times, not just a single time, right? Othwerwise this test is pointless. Anyway you surely can use that syntax, but be aware that in order to use it, you can´t call any property nor method on the provided agument, which would cause the exact same "problem" again. In your case it won´t matter, because the key is just a string, but if it was some class having some complex members as well, e.g. `key.MyProperty`, this would lead to the same behaviour

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok. Thanks :) What I've learnt here was that `private static` and `private` is mostly about semantics and emphasize the intent of the method. Performance speed up is insignificant and it's not worth to make that tradeoff :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> After you mark the methods as static, the compiler will emit non-virtual call sites to these members. Emitting non-virtual call sites will prevent a check at runtime for each call that ensures that the **current object pointer is non-null**. This can result in a measurable performance gain for performance-sensitive code. In some cases, the failure to access the current object instance represents a correctness issue.

I may be wrong, but I think you are mixing up the "current object pointer is non-null" check and the check of the argument passed into the static method `_key` in the static call `ValidateKeyStatic(_key);`

The first refers to the pointer on which you invoke the method. When you write the following call to a non static method:

`foo.Bar(blah)`

An automatic non null runtime check is inserted for `foo` and if it happens to be `null`, you get the infamous `ReferenceNullException` and your program crashes. This check is avoided if the method is static, hence the performance gain, because the method is not invoked on any particular instance of an object.

And it has nothing to do with what checks or not you may perfomr on `blah` insisde the method `Bar`.